# How to configure istio routing so that it sends all the traffic to one pod not the other?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have the following routing.yaml file and two services running on GKE cluster

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: prefix
spec:
  hosts:
    - frontend
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: frontend
          subset: prod
        weight: 100
---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: prefix
spec:
  hosts:
    - backend
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: backend
          subset: prod
        weight: 100
```

Now whenever I hit the http request I expect that my frontend-prod should get all the request and response should be the same. But it turns out it is different and worst part is other server gets hit randomly
Following is the output

```
http GET xx.xx.xx.xx:6756/get_prefix class==d 'Authorization: Token 95cd418693b14ddc87220430e7225ab5'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
content-length: 159
content-type: text/html
date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 09:32:25 GMT
server: istio-envoy
x-envoy-decorator-operation: frontend.prefix.svc.cluster.local:6756/*
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 4

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>YOUR TOKEN IS INVALID, YOU CAN'T ASK FOR PREFIX</p>
```

But some other time I get following

```
http GET xx.xx.xx.xx:6756/get_prefix class==d 'Authorization: Token 95cd418693b14ddc87220430e7225ab5'
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 143
content-type: text/html
date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 09:32:26 GMT
server: istio-envoy
x-envoy-decorator-operation: frontend.prefix.svc.cluster.local:6756/*
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 12

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Could not parse the request</p>
```

This does not make sense all the traffic should go to prod front end not the canary one. I can see the logs in both of the containers which confirms that request goes there.

Below is my service.yaml if it helps

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service

metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
  namespace: prefix

spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 6756
      targetPort: 6756
      name: http
```

Backend service file is similar with port 6757. 
How to make sure that traffic goes to one pod only?

```
kubectl get pods --namespace prefix
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
backend-canary-7978f77b58-7qzh6    2/2     Running   0          126m
backend-prod-5ff66456f9-zwxxn      2/2     Running   0          126m
frontend-canary-7dd5c45dfc-lcfh6   2/2     Running   0          126m
frontend-prod-7f6d9b5ddc-bkk5h     2/2     Running   0          126m
```

Comment: Do you have a matching DestinationRule object?

Comment: Nope, Doesn't VirtualService replace RouteRule ? 
I think we did not need it in RouteRule. I am new to this.

Comment: The `subset:` matches subsets declared in `DestinationRule` objects.  The [Request Routing](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/) sample in the Istio docs doesn't really highlight them, but there is a note at the top that it depends on a set of [destination rules](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/#apply-default-destination-rules) that match `subset:` to pod labels.

Comment: @DavidMaze Got it
This https://github.com/IBM/istio101/tree/master/workshop/exercise-6 was super helpful

Comment: @DavidMaze But still the LoadBalancer on the frontend routes the requests in the round-robin manner , I have corresponding DestinationRule for them. Though I got it done for the backend, but frontend still does the roundrobin. I guess that is because of GKE's LB ?

Comment: It seems you may have to enter traffic through Istio `istio-ingressgateway` External IP address and create [Gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/gateway/) resource in order to manage routes defined in `VirtualService` , `DestinationRule`.